# Django: Reverse for 'create_order' not found

Tags: python, django

I need an extra pair of eyes for this problem, can't find for hours what syntax mistake have I made this time or if Django syntax rules changed after some update I don't know about, from some reason, it just cannot find the `create_order`.

**dashboard.html**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'create_order' %}">Create Order</a>
```

**urls.py file**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('customer/<str:pk>/', views.customer, name="customer"),
    path('products/', views.products, name="products"),
    path('create_order/', views.createOrder, name="create_order"),
]
```

**views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from.models import *
def home(request):
    customers=Customer.objects.all()
    orders=Order.objects.all()
    total_customers=customers.count()
    total_orders=orders.count()
    delivered=orders.filter(status="Delivered").count()
    pending=orders.filter(status="Pending").count()
    context={'orders':orders,'customers':customers,
    'pending':pending, 'delivered':delivered,'total_orders':total_orders}
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html',context)

def products(request):      
    products = Product.objects.all()
    
    return render(request, 'accounts/products.html',{'products' :products})

def customer(request, pk):
    customer=Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders=customer.order_set.all()
    order_count=orders.count()
    context={'customer': customer, 'orders': orders,'order_count':order_count}
    return  render(request, 'accounts/customer.html', context)

def createOrder(request):
    context={}
    return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html',context)
```

**error by Django**

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'create_order' not found. 'create_order' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'create_order' not found. 'create_order' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Janek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Janek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Janek\\Desktop\\crm1',
 'C:\\Users\\Janek\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Janek\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Janek\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Janek\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
 'C:\\Users\\Janek\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Janek\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\Janek\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Janek\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Fri, 25 Sep 2020 09:23:37 +0000
```

**urls.py-crm1

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    
]
```

**

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    
]

Comment: please edit this in your question not here in the comments

Comment: done mate, in the very bottom

Comment: what is the name of your app which has these urls ?

Comment: which urls and which views? the views are from the accounts app and the urls up there also but the urls.py-crm1 are from the crm1

Comment: href="{% url 'appname:create_order' %}"

Answer (score 0):

your `urls.py` is in `accounts` app, right?

Do you have `apps.py` file in `accounts` directory too? It looks something like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'accounts' # <- this is the value you're looking for
```

take the `name` value and add it as `app_name` above the `urlpatterns` in your `urls.py` like this:

```
app_name = 'accounts' # the actual value of `name` from apps.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('customer/<str:pk>/', views.customer, name="customer"),
    path('products/', views.products, name="products"),
    path('create_order/', views.createOrder, name="create_order"),
]
```

then use it with the prefix:

```
{% url 'accounts:create_order' %}
```